# function outputs

Tags: functions

I've been trying to answer this question and am a bit stuck.

Let f: N \ {0} -> N \ {0} be the function where the output is the number of positive integer factors of the input. For example, f(15) = 4 since there are positive integer factors of 15, namely 1, 3, 5, 15.

a) find f(n) for all n between 1 and 20 inclusive.
b) is f an injective function?
c) if f(n) is odd, what can we say about n?
d) if p is a prime, what is f(p)?
e) if n = pr (meant to be p to the power of r), where p is prime, and r is a positive integer, find formula for f(n).
f) give a specific number n, if possible, such that f(n) = 10, 017. is f a surjective (onto) function?

i have answers for a, b and d but am a bit confused on how to determine c, e and f. if anyone could explain this it'll be a big help thank you! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c) If $f(n)$ is odd, that means you can pair up all of the factors except for one, which pairs up with itself.  What kind of number can be factored into two identical integers?  I'd say $n$ would have to be a perfect square.

e) If $n=p^r$ where $p$ is a prime number and $r$ is a positive integer, what can you say about $f(n)$?  Well how can you factor a power of a prime number?  It's only prime factors are that prime number.  How many of them?  $r$ prime factors.  So $f(p^r)=r$.

f) What is the value of $n$ if $f(n)=10017$?  Well since we know that $f(p^r)=r$ from the last problem, just use any prime $p$ raised to the 10017th power, like $2^{10017}$ for instance.  I'm not sure about the second part.